# reputable location to download jeromq binary?

Tags: java, jeromq

I've been using [jeromq](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq) for the last 6 months or so, and I'm getting a colleague up to speed. Is there any reputable location to download a JAR file? The version I have is jeromq-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar but I can't remember for the life of me where it came from, and I want to get him a legitimate version.

(Yes, I can build from source too, but I would rather give a colleague a link to a reputable website than send him a .jar file from my computer or force him to build from source.)

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: whatever; this is a legitimate question for non-expert Java programmers. Anyway I got the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the maven repository? 
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.zeromq%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jeromq%22

Though I don't see the snapshot there.

Direct link to latest jar (0.3.4 at this time): http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/zeromq/jeromq/0.3.4/jeromq-0.3.4.jar